# Style Captcha image and textbox in one line

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, recaptcha, captcha

I want to display captcha image and textbox in one line in razor page.It has `<br>` tags. is it possible to remove `<br` tags using css or how can I resolve this ? (Package CaptchaMvc version 1.5)

`login.cshtml` >

```
@using CaptchaMvc.Interface
@{
    ICaptcha captcha = Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter Verification Code ", 4, "The Captcha is required", true);
}
```

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    @captcha.RenderMarkup()
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it will return HTML String than you can manipulate a string like your wish Replace all line break to emptyspace
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var captcha = Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter Verification Code ", 4, "The Captcha is required", true);
    var captchaStr = captcha.RenderMarkup().ToHtmlString().Replace("<br/>","");
}
<div style="float:left">
   @Html.Raw(captchaStr);
</div>
```

Comment: Is it posibble to add image for refresh button and put CaptchaInputText and enter code text in another div of same line. one div for image and refresh anothe div for text

Comment: furthermore add image refresh button for refresh text